# Node Js Migration issue (Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError Specified key was too long )

Tags: mysql, node.js, migration, mariadb, sequelize-cli

I am using Sequelize package for database migration in Node js
Database is ber 15.1 Distrib MariaDB 10.1.44-MariaDB
When I run 'npm run start', got this error
[image]

this is my migration file code

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.addColumn(
        'users',
        'county',
        {
          type:Sequelize.STRING
        }
    )},


  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.removeColumn('users', 'county')
  }

};
```

Comment: 5 options for 767 error problem:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using MariaDB version 10.1.44.
I upgrade version to Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.22-MariaDB

then it works properly
This is the guide to install and upgrade mariadb 10.3

[mariadb-10-3-11-available-heres-how-to-install-upgrade-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-18-10/](https://websiteforstudents.com/mariadb-10-3-11-available-heres-how-to-install-upgrade-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-18-10/)